# Is downloaded from Nexus automatically an existing dependency in local?

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

I have two projects (Parent and Son). The Son project depends on the Parent project. The Parent project have a permanent version (and the Parent is in Nexus as release) and I have a job in Jenkins which works well.

If I make a change in the Parent and I redeploy in Nexus (same group, artifact, version), during the Jenkins job is detected that there is a "new dependency" or should I delete the old dependency manually for getting the new one (this new dependency is the modified Parent).

Answer (score 1):

In maven you are not supposed to redeploy released artifacts
Once you release 1.0, you need to go to 1.1-SNAPSHOT and then to 1.1

You can technically delete 1.0 and redeploy it but you will screw your clients since the clients won't download the new 1.0 since they locally have the old 1.0 already.

Now if nobody has downloaded 1.0 from nexus then you can remove it and redeploy it without problem

So, the short answer is, increase your version after you deploy a release version

Comment: I know that (probably I explained myself wrong). When I run the Jenkins job the second time, and now in Nexus the Parent content has changed but the version is the same. The jenkins jobs works with the new Parent or works with the old Parent (they have always the same version)

Comment: You will use the old version. May be you have configured to clean up the local repository of your job and that will might solve the problem. But this is completely against the idea of Maven releases. For such purposes SNAPSHOT's exist.

Comment: @IkerAguayo what do you know? that you are supposed to increase the version after a release? if so, why do you need to do same-version redeploys then if you know it's not recommended? that way we'll be able to offer a more accurate answer or suggest an alternate way to solve your problem

Comment: I know that goes against Maven idea. But about my question, it would be used the old version. Is there a way to clean the local repository in the job in every build?

Comment: Yes, you can tell jenkins to use a new local repo per build, but again, it goes against standard practices and will screw other clients (non-jenkins clients) that use a normal repo. Look for `Use private Maven repository` in the jenkins config
but the better solution if you find yourself doing this is to use "RC-x" qualifiers. seriously, don't redeploy release artifacts